# My React Index.css didn't change any component styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

so I am trying to learn react for my web development framework and I am trying to add styling (CSS) to my component, but it didn't work.

My Index.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid steelblue;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

My App.js

```
import Header from './components/Header'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <button>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: where do you import index.css?

Answer (score 0):

did you import your css file?

you must import your css file in index.js or app.js

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `import './Index.css'` at `App.js`. You can read more ways how to connect css files to your react component [here](https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822)

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the import statement.In index.js, add the import statement

```
import './index.css'
```